# Создать список с переменным кол-вом элементов (reactjs, es6)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Для создания элементов, создаю новый компонент. Проблема в написании, используя синтаксис ES6. Пробую так:

```
var Content = React.createClass({
 render() {
    return(
        var content = array.map( (item) => {
            return <li>{item}</li>
        }
     );
  }
});
```

Выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну во первых, почему не написали, что это за ошибка, а во вторых, почему не `class Content extends React.Component {}`. Так же ссылочные функции можно писать сразу `array.map( (item) => <li>{item}</li>`, тогда `return` съедается

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде есть сразу несколько проблем:

1. Определение переменной в методе `render` явно лишнее. Именно этот момент должен вызывать синтаксическую ошибку.
2. Компонент React должен возвращать ровно один элемент (хотя этот элемент вполне может иметь дочерние элементы).
3. Непонятно откуда появилась переменная `array`.
4. Блок в "стрелочной функции" явно лишний. Ошибкой это не является, но выглядит очень уж дико.

Правильный код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
var Content = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

Думаю вам все-таки стоит начать с изучения основ React.